# Запрет редактирования содержимого TV параметра из админки в modX

Tags: modx

Дорабатываю сайт, созданный с помощью modX, после другого разработчика. Столкнулся с проблемой, что нет возможности редактировать содержимое определенных TV параметров на всех страницах сайта. В частности, есть TV параметр, в котором находятся четыре элемента с изображением, заголовком и описанием, но нет возможности удалить один из них или добавить новый.

Answer (score 1):

1. Зайдите в свойства tv-параметра (`элементы -> дополнительные поля`) и на вкладке `общая информация`, убедитесь, что снят флаг `Запретить редактирование дополнительного поля`
2. На вкладке `Права доступа` посмотрите, какой группе разрешен доступ к редактированию информации этого поля, и либо удалите эти строки - тогда все пользователи админки будут иметь возможность редактировать поле, либо зайдите в `контроль доступа` и добавьте для своего пользователя права на группу ресурсов